# Slow dripping pipe freeze?

Tags: plumbing

I just noticed that our outside faucet is very slowly dripping and I can't shut it completely off.

[Video of drip](http://d.pr/v/yGIn)

We have a hard freeze happening tomorrow. Should I be overly concerned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said "*hard freeze*", I'm guessing your from an area where it normally doesn't get below freezing.  If this is the case, and the cold temperatures aren't going to last more than a day or two. You likely won't have any problems, since the heat from the home should keep the water above freezing (assuming the plumbing is in conditioned space, before going outside).

If you have a shutoff for that faucet inside the house, I'd definitely close that one and open the outdoor faucet.

If the freeze is going to last a few days, you could open the faucet a bit to allow the water to trickle.  Moving water tends to not freeze as quickly, so letting it run could prevent it from freezing.

There are also insulated hose bib covers available, which can be installed to prevent freezing. Since your bib is leaking, this may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

There will be another shut off inside in your basement hopefully near the faucet. The pipe will be copper and 5/8" in diameter. Either a handle that you turn 90 degrees perpendicular to the pipe or just like the faucet that you turn clockwise to close. Close that and open the outside faucet (otherwise known as winterizing) And if you didn't do this before last winter your faucet already froze and you need a new one.

[Another related post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36324/how-to-shut-off-water-valve-to-outside-faucet?rq=1)

Comment: The OP may not have a basement, not all plumbing is copper, an there's no guarantee that the pipe will be 5/8".   While all this *may* be true in your home; and maybe your area in general, this site serves a large geographic area. Try to make your answers a bit more general, and they'll appeal to a wider audience.